# Sending Alertmanager alerts to my email address with Jenkins mailer webhook

Tags: jenkins-plugins, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have my Alertmanager up and running and I can see all active alerts on alertmanager dashboard.

Now I want an email notification for alerts based on created rules.

1. I tried getting internal smtp details but seems like its a very hectic task in organizational env.
2. For other small tasks, we use Jenkins webhook to send an email notification to our org email address and it works.
3. I assume there is something I can do to integrate alertmanager with Jenkins and send alerts to my email address, but not completely sure how to do that.

   I was wondering If someone can redirect me to a relevant post or a brief HowTo to achieve this model.

   thanks in advance.

Comment: It something similar what you want to achieve? https://www.reddit.com/r/devops/comments/gn83j6/custom_prometheus_webhook_alert_to_api/